# Is there an alternate way to calculate beyond the memory limit of the home edition?

Tags: numerics, warning-messages, memory, mathematica-online

I bought the Home Edition of Mathematica online 0.5 G of memory and costs \$150 per year. When I calculated the median of outputs from $[0,1]$ with an interval of $.000001$ I ended up with the follwoing

```
Median[Table[2^x-x,{x,0,1,.000001}]]
0.935553527528773
```

Then I tried a smaller interval of $.0000001$ and got.

```
Median[Table[2^x-x,{x,0,1,.0000001}]
Cloud::memlimit :  *This computation has exceeded the memory limit for your plan*
```

I had limited knowledge of mathematica and am taking a college course on its next year. I tried the documentations but found little. Is there a way of calculating interval up to and smaller than seven digits without switching to the standard edition that costs \$950 per year?

Comment: Shouldn't the exact value be $2^{0.5} - 0.5$?, but it doesn't approach this.

Comment: Most calculations can be done with limited memory (writing intermediate results to disk) if you are prepared to put enough effort into writing the software.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Than the probelm could be my browser or the online version of mathematica.

Comment: @Feyre the function `2^x-x` is not monotonic on [0 1]

Comment: @Mr.Wizard The calculation in question uses ~320 MB on my machine: `In[132]:= Median[Table[2^x - x, {x, 0, 1, .0000001}]] // MaxMemoryUsed

Out[132]= 320000792`

Comment: @Arbuja Has it been a long session, with `$HistoryLength === Infinity`?

Comment: `MaxMemoryUsed[Median[Table[2^x - x, {x, 0, 1, .0000001}]]]` (with `0.0000001 = 10.^-7`) yields around `320,000,000` (320MB), which is very close to your 0.5GB limit.

Comment: You may be able to compute the median of a large set by reexpressing as a minimization problem e.g. `Minimize[Sum[Abs[(2^x - x) - y], {x, 0, 1, 0.00001}], y]`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I'll try that and tell you if they can fix it.

Comment: Made edits. Digits are fixed.

Comment: I see that the code in the question has been changed so my comments regarding memory are now invalid.

Comment: FWIW, the answer is `Root[{-(Log[2]/2) + ProductLog[-2^-#1 Log[2]] - 
    ProductLog[-1, -2^-#1 Log[2]] &, 
  0.935553478022935551757231992253}]`.

Comment: @Coolwater I restarted and the history length is still infinite.

Comment: @mikado I tried minimize and it aborted.

Comment: @ChipHurst Is there a formula for calcuating the median of outputs. I looked everywhere and couldn't find it.

Comment: I'll post what I did as an answer. It's essentially what @mikado did but in integral form.

Comment: Since you have, from larger intervals, a good estimate of the Median, use less memory, more time and a little trial and error to get closer to the median with smaller intervals. lo=0; hi=0; guess=935554/10^6; For[x=0, x<=1, x+=10^-6, If[2^x-x<guess, lo++, hi++]]; {lo, hi} which uses almost no memory and a little more time and much less deep mathematical knowledge. You could try to automate that search, which will be more complicated, but might teach you something at the same time.

Comment: @mikado How did you figure this out using minimization. Is there any source?

Comment: It is a standard result - see for example http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/113270/the-median-minimizes-the-sum-of-absolute-deviations - and quite easy to prove

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, here's the answer to how I got the median.

I found the value $y$ that minimized

$$ f(y) = \int_0^1 \left| 2^x-x-y \right| dx. $$

First, to break up the absolute value in the integrand, I solved for when $2^x = y$:

```
Solve[(2^x - x) == y && 9/10 < y < 1, x, Reals]
```

[image]

Then I integrated and found where $f'(y) = 0$:

```
int = Integrate[2^x - x - y, {x, 0, b1}] 
      - Integrate[2^x - x - y, {x, b1, b2}] 
      + Integrate[2^x - x - y, {x, b2, 1}];

Solve[D[int, y] == 0 && 9/10 < y < 1, y, Reals]
```

> ```
> {{y -> Root[{-(Log[2]/2) + ProductLog[-2^-#1 Log[2]] - 
>    ProductLog[-1, -2^-#1 Log[2]] &, 0.935553478022935551757231992253}]}}
> ```

I decided to keep things symbolic in hopes of a nice looking answer. A numeric adaptation would probably be much easier.

Comment: That is amazing! Is there a mathematical textbook on this or is it simply logic?

Comment: Well I essentially just did what mikado did, but in integral form. It seems like it would be the median, but I have no source...